# Logic to override SaveAll?

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud

I would like to override the `saveAll` function depending on a value in the Database (not the primary Key).

```
@Repository
public interface ConfluencePageRepository extends CrudRepository<ConfluencePageReport, Long> {

}
```

We got the function `saveAll(List list)` from the `CRUDRepository`, and I would like it to save all my entities as it does but check before by a specific value.

If this entity doesn't exist in the DB, that is why I would like to customize the function.

Comment: Can you post the code here? Please produce a minimal,reproducible example so that we can help you. Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: of course .. i will try my best to explain it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad idea and you should rethink your approach. By the way, this is the type of thing you want to do in the service layer, in the context of a transaction.

Also, you are not advised to check if the value exists in the database in the way you are planning to do. If you have different threads persisting the same set of data at the same time, you’ll likely to end up with inconsistent data.

Finally, unless you acquire a table-level lock (I don’t think you want that), you’d better create constraints in the database and then handle exceptions (such as [`DataIntegrityViolationException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html)) in your service layer.